# Deploying capistrano fails by ssh error when running `bundle install`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, ssh, capistrano

I'm using `Capistrano 3` to deploy a Rails project to VPS server(CentOS 6.5).

Last time about 2 month ago I could deploy without problem, but now I can't deploy by ssh error when running `bundle install` at the VPS server.

I updated ruby version `2.0.0-p451` to `2.1.1`, but it doesn't change error message.

This is the error messages:

```
INFO[057e025d] Running RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet on example.com
DEBUG[057e025d] Command: cd /var/www/example.com/releases/20140823122915 && ( RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv RBENV_VERSION=2.1.1 /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec bundle install --binstubs /var/www/example.com/shared/bin --path /var/www/example.com/shared/bundle --without development test --deployment --quiet )
DEBUG[057e025d]     Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for "au-m.rubygems.org" port 443 (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-10.3.2.gem)
DEBUG[057e025d]     An error occurred while installing rake (10.3.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
DEBUG[057e025d]     Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.3.2'` succeeds before bundling.
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host example.com: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written

SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written

Tasks: TOP => deploy:updated => bundler:install
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: #<SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing on host example.com: bundle exit status: 5
bundle stdout: Nothing written
bundle stderr: Nothing written
```

I could install `rake (10.3.2)` by `# gem install rake` at the server manually like this:

```
rake's executable "rake" conflicts with /usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.1.1/bin/rake
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  y
Successfully installed rake-10.3.2
Parsing documentation for rake-10.3.2
Installing ri documentation for rake-10.3.2
Done installing documentation for rake after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

But even after updating the deploy error persists same.

What should I do to remove the error?
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the server "au-m.rubygems.org" was down.

That was the reason of the error.